# Циклы ломают всё

Tags: java

Есть: массив StringBuilder but, StringBuilder str и массив int indexes.
Добавляю в массив строителей строки до тех пор, пока а меньше размера другого массива (в этом массиве нужные индексы)

```
ArrayList<StringBuilder> but = new ArrayList<>();
for (a = 0; a < indexes.size(); a++){
but.add(str);};
```

Теперь мне нужно удалить из 1-го StringBuilder (из массива) символы до определенного индекса (из другого массива). Я делаю это так:

```
but.get(1).delete(0, indexes.get(1));
```

И это работает (и с 0, и с 2 вместо 1), но если я сделаю цикл:

```
a = 0;
while (a < indexes.size()){
but.get(a).delete(0, indexes.get(a));}
```

То приложение просто останавливается, крашится, вылетает.

**UPD:** Mea kulpa, дамы и господа, я дурак, но даже так:

```
a = 0;
while (a < indexes.size()){
but.get(a).delete(0, indexes.get(a));
a++;}
```

он ломается.

Comment: `try ... catch` и смотрите причину ошибки. С учетом того, что `а` не меняется в цикле, то он будет выполняться бесконечно

Comment: А чего вы пытаетесь достичь? Я вижу только бесконечный цикл, на каждой итерации которого, вы удаляете из StringBuilder (который у вас один и тот же в каждом элементе `but`) первые `indexes.get(0)` символов. Логично, что когда-то символы закончатся

Comment: а почему бы просто при добавлении не пропускать элементы пока не дойдете до вашего индекса? Вообще, какая у вас задача?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, но ведь я каждый новый a беру новый StringBuilder (новый элемент массива)

Comment: В процедуре добавления `but.add(str);` вы добавляете один и тот же объект во все элементы списка

Comment: @trollingchar, вообще есть текст (значение текста содержит каждый элемент массива), в котором есть одинаковые слова, индексы этих слов я поместил в массив. Мне нужно получить новое слово, следующее после определенного. Я беру первый элемент массива строителей, удаляю из него часть текста до определенного слова, я делаю это для всех совпадений, которых indexes.size(). Как-то так :)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, значит ли это то, что я каждый раз меняю str, а не элемент массива. То есть элемент массива не копирует str, а как бы ссылается на него?

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов Именно так

Comment: Спасибо большое всем! Благодаря вам я понял, что в ArrayList элементы вносятся, а не копируют значение того, что вносят.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставь проверку на длинну `but`, чтобы когда длинна меньше `but`, чем кол-во символов, которые ты хочешь обрезать не вылетала ошибка. Также эта проверка нужна, чтобы ты циклом не изрезал массив до пустосты.